# SELECT from MySQL database based on 2 parameters

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs

I got 2 variables in my React app: startDate and endDate and I want to fetch data from database based on these parameters like this:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost/api/date?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`).then((response)
=> {
      this.setState(() => ({ data: response.data}));
    });
```

I am using MySQL database and PHP.

Currently my backend looks like this, as you can see I am just selecting all from my database table:

```
<?php 
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request; 
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

// Get All Calendar Dates 
$app->get('/api/date', function(Request $request, Response $response){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM datescalendar";

    try{
        // Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        // Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $dates = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        // return $response->withJson($dates);
        echo json_encode($dates);
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    } });
```

How to change my query to select from my database table based on these 2 parameters I have in my React app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BETWEEN` operator like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `datescalendar` where `date` BETWEEN '{$start_date}' AND '{$end_date}'";
```

the dates must be in format `Y-m-d` if the field is a `datetime` then format should be `Y-m-d H:i:s`